# VirtualDocumentRoot and ProxyPassMatch

Tags: php, php-fpm, httpd, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I have the following Apache configuration:

```
ServerName localhost
UseCanonicalName Off

LogLevel debug

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName _default_

    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/alex/Sites/op3/cms/account/%-2/domain/%-3+/webroot
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,PT]

    LogLevel rewrite:trace6
    LogLevel proxy:trace6

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.php)(\?.*)?$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/Users/alex/Sites/op3/cms/$1$2

    <Directory /Users/alex/Sites/op3/cms>
        Options +Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The path in `ProxyPassMatch` is not correct, but I'm not sure how I should be constructing the path.  Using the same `%-2` and `%-3+` tokens in ProxyPassMatch does not appear to work.  I have attempted to use [another solution I found](http://float64.uk/blog/2014/08/22/dynamic-development-area-apache-php-fpm/), but this was the best I could come up with:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000/Users/alex/Sites/op3/cms/account/%-2/domain/%-3+/webroot/$1
```

...and this didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting or why is it not working correctly? What version of Apache are you using?